# SSRS Check if Parameter exists

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where the user must enter an order number, this then populates tables and charts etc.

What I need to know is how do I go about informing the user that they have entered an invalid order number?

so a sort of 'IF @ORDERNO IN (SELECT DISTINCT ORDERNO FROM ORDERS) then the data will be displayed else a textbox will show at the top of the report saying Invalid Order No.

I could provide them with a list of OrderNumbers to select from as the parameter but there's too many to make this feasible.

I know you can add a Textbox with an expression with an IIF and check a value, but is it possible to check that value exists in a dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Is norowmessage property of the table works for you?

> Select your table->press F4-> Put relevant message under
>   **NoRowsMessgae** property

Answer (score 0):

Create another parameter and have it populate the order # if it exists.

Parameter1: Enter Order: 54455

DataSet2: `Select 'Valid Order' As "Confirmation" from Order_Table where Order_number = :Parameter1`

Set Default Value of Parameter2 to display Confirmation value as Default

This way, they'll know if they have the right order even before they run the report.